# How to highlight a command when syntax is already loaded in VIM?

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting

How can I highlight all instances of one particular TeX command `\foo` after having loaded the default `tex` syntax scheme in VIM (v7.2)?

I can do it easily if no syntax scheme is antecedently loaded:

```
:syntax clear
:highlight myGroup ctermfg=blue
:syntax match myGroup "\\foo\>"
```

But I don't know how to do it when the `tex` syntax scheme is loaded.
This doesn't work:

```
:syntax clear
:set syntax=tex
:highlight myGroup ctermfg=blue
:syntax match myGroup "\\foo\>"
```

#### Update 1

Actually, it works for commands in the preamble but not for those inside the `document` environment.

#### Update 2

A workaround is to comment out some lines in `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/tex.vim` (v47) which handle folding:

```
" Sections, subsections, etc: {{{1
if g:tex_fold_enabled && has("folding")
 syn region texDocZone                  matchgroup=texSection start='\\begin\s*{\s*document\s*}' end='\\end\s*{\s*document\s*}'                                                     fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texDocGroup,@Spell
 syn region texPartZone                 matchgroup=texSection start='\\part\>'                   end='\ze\s*\\\%(part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'                                  fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texPartGroup,@Spell
 syn region texChapterZone              matchgroup=texSection start='\\chapter\>'                end='\ze\s*\\\%(chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'                       fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texChapterGroup,@Spell
 syn region texSectionZone              matchgroup=texSection start='\\section\>'                end='\ze\s*\\\%(section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'            fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texSectionGroup,@Spell
 syn region texSubSectionZone           matchgroup=texSection start='\\subsection\>'             end='\ze\s*\\\%(\%(sub\)\=section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'  fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texSubSectionGroup,@Spell
 syn region texSubSubSectionZone        matchgroup=texSection start='\\subsubsection\>'          end='\ze\s*\\\%(\%(sub\)\{,2}section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texSubSubSectionGroup,@Spell
 syn region texParaZone                 matchgroup=texSection start='\\paragraph\>'              end='\ze\s*\\\%(paragraph\>\|\%(sub\)*section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'                       fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@texParaGroup,@Spell
 syn region texSubParaZone              matchgroup=texSection start='\\subparagraph\>'           end='\ze\s*\\\%(\%(sub\)\=paragraph\>\|\%(sub\)*section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'     fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@Spell
 syn region texTitle                    matchgroup=texSection start='\\\%(author\|title\)\>\s*{' end='}'                                                                            fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@Spell
 syn region texAbstract                 matchgroup=texSection start='\\begin\s*{\s*abstract\s*}' end='\\end\s*{\s*abstract\s*}'                                                     fold contains=@texFoldGroup,@Spell
"else
" syn region texDocZone                 matchgroup=texSection start='\\begin\s*{\s*document\s*}' end='\\end\s*{\s*document\s*}'                                                     contains=@texFoldGroup,@texDocGroup,@Spell
" syn region texPartZone                        matchgroup=texSection start='\\part\>'                   end='\ze\s*\\\%(part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'                          contains=@texFoldGroup,@texPartGroup,@Spell
" syn region texChapterZone             matchgroup=texSection start='\\chapter\>'                end='\ze\s*\\\%(chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'                       contains=@texFoldGroup,@texChapterGroup,@Spell
" syn region texSectionZone             matchgroup=texSection start='\\section\>'                end='\ze\s*\\\%(section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'            contains=@texFoldGroup,@texSectionGroup,@Spell
" syn region texSubSectionZone          matchgroup=texSection start='\\subsection\>'             end='\ze\s*\\\%(\%(sub\)\=section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'  contains=@texFoldGroup,@texSubSectionGroup,@Spell
" syn region texSubSubSectionZone       matchgroup=texSection start='\\subsubsection\>'          end='\ze\s*\\\%(\%(sub\)\{,2}section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'contains=@texFoldGroup,@texSubSubSectionGroup,@Spell
" syn region texParaZone                        matchgroup=texSection start='\\paragraph\>'              end='\ze\s*\\\%(paragraph\>\|\%(sub\)*section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'                       contains=@texFoldGroup,@texParaGroup,@Spell
" syn region texSubParaZone             matchgroup=texSection start='\\subparagraph\>'           end='\ze\s*\\\%(\%(sub\)\=paragraph\>\|\%(sub\)*section\>\|chapter\>\|part\>\|end\s*{\s*document\s*}\)'     contains=@texFoldGroup,@Spell
" syn region texTitle                   matchgroup=texSection start='\\\%(author\|title\)\>\s*{' end='}'                                                                            contains=@texFoldGroup,@Spell
" syn region texAbstract                        matchgroup=texSection start='\\begin\s*{\s*abstract\s*}' end='\\end\s*{\s*abstract\s*}'                                             contains=@texFoldGroup,@Spell
endif
```

Comment: It works for me in Vim 7.3. Can you reproduce it in the absence of any plugins (run `vim -u NONE`)?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you. Unfortunately, Vim 7.2 is the newest version in Debian (stable).

Comment: @PrinceGoulash: Does it work for you if `\foo` is inside the `document` environment? It only works for me if `\foo` is in the preamble. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is existing syntax highlighting, so your `:syntax match` isn't applied. You need to find out which original syntax group highlights it and `contain` it in there. This works for me:

```
:syntax match myGroup "\\foo\>" containedin=texStatement
```